# Prove that $\frac{a^3}{b-c}+\frac{b^3}{a-c}+\frac{c^3}{a-b} \geq \frac{3}{2} (ab+bc+ac)$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that $$\frac{a^3}{b-c}+\frac{b^3}{a-c}+\frac{c^3}{a-b} \geq
>  \frac{3}{2} (ab+bc+ac)$$ where $$a, b, c >0$$

I have tried using the AM/GM inequality but I ended up with an expression involving cubing both sides, so I figured that there must be an easier way.

Comment: have you thought about cases of a,b and c ?

Comment: If you have, have you considered that when a=b, or b=c, or c=a that you are dividing by 0 on the LHS. Also, and this might be because I'm dumb, but can't you multiply both sides by $2\over3$, and get a set of sums of three numbers on each side. If two of these parts are equal, then one has to be at least as big if not bigger of the one remaining on each side.

Comment: As stated, the inequality is not always true. For example, if 
$$a=1,\;\;c=2b$$
the LHS approaches $-\infty$ as $b \to 0^{+}$.

Comment: The inequality fails. A concrete counterexample is $(a, b, c)=(1, 2, 3)$.

Comment: Using Calculus (and with help from Maple), I can show the inequality holds if $a > b > c > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $a>b>c>0$ we can kill it by BW:
Let $b=c+u$ and $a=c+u+v$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$2(u^2+3uv+v^2)c^3+3(u^2+uv+2v^2)vc^2+$$
$$+6(2u+v)v^3c+(u^4+2u^3v+9u^2v^2+8uv^3+2v^4)v\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Comment: Simple and nice.

Comment: But you meant $a = ...$, not $x= ...$.

Comment: @quasi I fixed my post. Thank you!

Comment: Rozenberg, inequality is your life, I think :)

Comment: Rozenberg, there is a mistake in question. Must be  $a≠b≠c$

Comment: @MathLife For $a\neq b$, $a\neq c$ and $b\neq c$ try $a-b\rightarrow0^-$. It must be $a>b>c$.

Comment: Did you try $a,b,c=>1,2,3$ ?

Comment: Hmmm,.the user must edit question $a>b>c$

Comment: @MathLife For $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=3$ our inequality is wrong. Yes! It must be edited.